# TypeError: __init__() takes at most 6 arguments (7 given) python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

if backtest:

```
            poloData = self.conn.api_query("returnChartData",{"currencyPair":self.pair,"start":self.startTime,"end":self.endTime,"period":self.period})

            for datum in poloData:

                if (datum['open'] and datum['close'] and datum['high'] and datum['low']):

                    self.data.append(BotCandlestick(self.period,datum['open'],datum['close'],datum['high'],datum['low'],datum['weightedAverage']))
```

how can I remedy this? I'm fairly new

Answer (score 0):

I guess I answered my own question, self is an argument, so the problem lies with the bot candlestick parent class. As soon as I took that out it worked.